# Javafx - CheckBox throws exception when double click

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I added to a pie chart a panel with check boxes that the pie will show when the match check box is checked. The problem is when the user is double clicking on the check box, them it throws IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added

The code of the check box event:

```
private void valueChecked(CheckBox checkBox, Data checkedData) {
    try {
        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
            if (!pieChart.getData().contains(checkedData)) {
                pieChart.getData().add(checkedData);
            }
        } else {
            pieChart.getData().remove(checkedData);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

The exception stack trace:

```
= java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Chart$1@3a52471[styleClass=chart-content]
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
at javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.dataItemAdded(PieChart.java:423)
at javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.lambda$new$574(PieChart.java:171)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
at pieChartPane.valueChecked(PieChartPane.java:103)
at pieChartPane.lambda$0(PieChartPane.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.fire(CheckBox.java:239)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What the problem can be? who is the duplicate child from the exception?

Comment: It's obvious - you try to put duplicate. Did you run valueChecked in Platform.runLater? Could you share a bit more?

Comment: @VladislavKysliy it run on javafx thread so no need to run inside Platform.runLater. where do you see a duplication? before i add the check box i am checking that the pie chart not contain him

Comment: Could have a flag that determines whether it's already been added. Could have the node added to the graph, but hidden, then show/hide it instead of adding/removing if it's reasonable for your requirements. Point is, the program is attempting to add a node that already exists on the scene graph, which you need to account for/prevent. Although this does sound like a race condition, based on your comment "*wait few seconds and then check it again it works*", which if it is, my first suggestion would not work, and the second may be inconsistent

Comment: You should share some more code. As everyone said, you are trying to put duplicate.

Comment: "Who is the duplicate child from the exception?". Assuming line 103 is `pieChart.getData().add(checkedData)`, the duplicate child can only be the node that is a [property of `checkedData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.Data.html#nodeProperty). Unfortunately (and this is a terrible design), the chart data classes contain references to the nodes that are used to display them, which violates MVC and means that the same data cannot be used in more than one chart, or added twice to the same chart (as it results in the node appearing twice in the scene graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likley occurs because you add the same instance of `checkedData` two times to the SceneGraph.

This code produces the same "duplicate children" exception:

```
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
Data data = new PieChart.Data("myData", 17.56);     
pieChart.getData().add(data);
pieChart.getData().add(data);
```

While this code works:

```
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
Data data1 = new PieChart.Data("myData", 17.11);
Data data2 = new PieChart.Data("myData", 17.11);
pieChart.getData().add(data1);
pieChart.getData().add(data2);
```

See the difference?

Without seeing the whole code, it is difficult to say why this happens in your code. So, maybe your `contains` check does not work. Maybe you have added `checkedData` elsewhere to the scene graph already. And when you say this happens when doubleclicking, it also could be a race condition, if you are working with threads here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Technically, of course, `checkedData` isn't added to the scene graph at all, since it's not a node. The issue is that the chart `Data` classes keep a reference to the node that is used to display them (which is, frankly, the stupidest part of the whole JavaFX API). Consequently, data can't be added to a chart multiple times (or, say, reused in two different charts). IMHO this (and other Chart API deficiencies) makes the Chart API unsuitable for production code, sadly.

Comment: Yes, i oversimplified to make it more intelligible. Thanks for adding these details/correction.

Comment: I understand. I thought it was probably worth expanding, as it's very counterintuitive that data can't be reused, and not at all obvious that the data contains references to the view used to present it.

Comment: Thanks, i just duplicated the data and added it back